# Cannot access site groups with user with manage hierarchy permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom form that lists the site groups and the users in each group.

the form has twi drop down lists: one to display the site's group and the other to display the users in that group.

when I log to the form with the administrator user it works fine.

But if I log in with a user with manage hierarchy permission level, it omly displays the info of the domain groups and if I try to access a sharepoint group I get an access denied error.

I use run with elevated permissions in my code

I really don't know what to do in this

thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code (the part inside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges block specifically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two common mistakes when using RunWithElevatedPrivileges is:

1. Using the `SPContext.Current.Web` (or Site etc) won't change the identity of the web object, it is already in memory.
2. Declaring the SPWeb outside the delegate, with similar results of mistake 1

That said, try something like:

```
Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.Id;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => 
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(siteId))
using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.RootWeb)
{
   //impl
});
```